# How to change color in the header of the Einstein Bot

Tags: einstein, embedded-services

As much as I put the header as blue

[image]

When the web page load, the header show black, why?

[image]

in this documentation https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.snapins_chat_branding.htm&type=5 don't say anything about this... before talk with bot this header black is default?

Answer (score 0):

You can find in this option: Embedded Service Deployment Settings
in the setup.